# How to work with checkboxes in relation to database?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Hi I am trying to build a form with checkboxes and upon submitting the form, I want to see which checkboxes were checked and update the database accordingly.  How is this done?  I've tried so many different code and none of them worked.  The closest I've gotten was to update only the checked ones.  I also need to update the database if they are unchecked as well like a toggle.

So far my code is like this for the form

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type=checkbox" value="<?php echo member['id']; ?>" name="member[]" />
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
</form>
```

And for the PHP loop I have (excerpt)

```
foreach ((array)$_POST['test'] as $member) :
$sql = "UPDATE `sp_members` SET `allow_test` = '1' WHERE `id` = '$member'";
```

Since I think the loop only picks up the checkboxes that are checked, it doesn't pick up the ones that were orignally checked and now unchecked...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: So you basically want to update them in every case?

Comment: Yes, I want to update the database if checked becomes unchecked and vice versa..

Answer (score 0):

Simply update everything instead of trying to figure out what changed - if you programmed it yourself, you would have to make your code a lot more complicated, and as the database is already optimized for speed, it's better to just stuff it in the DB and let it handle it.

Comment: Wouldn't that be inefficient if say I had 1000s of records?  And can you post the code necessary on how you do it your way?

Comment: @Rick: The alternative to my solution would be to either put the old data in hidden inputs or to let the client only send the difference which would require it to use javascript.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil, you know. Build working code, identify bottlenecks, _then_ optimize these bottlenecks _only_. They may occur in places very different from where you thought they would.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary operator to set the correct value.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `sp_members` SET `allow_test` = '" 
     . ( $_REQUEST['checkbox'] ? 1 : 0 ) 
     . "' WHERE `id` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $member ) . "'";
```

It checks $_REQUEST['checkbox'] for a non-null, non-zero string and if true, returns 1, if false, returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
(($_post['member']) ?$allow_test = 1 : $allow_test = 0;
$sql = "UPDATE `sp_members` SET `allow_test` = $allow_test  WHERE `id` = '$member'";
```

Comment: I tried it this way and it works for checked..but it won't let me uncheck the item...

Comment: what is ur table structure : sp_members ? & is the value of the checkbox value in realtion give the real time eg:

Comment: 1:In database keep only the checked one 2: For next update delete records from database related to that member id & fire update query again.3: depending upond the results decide to keep the checkbos checked or unchecked

Comment: Why do u also need to update the database if they are unchecked bcoz you can get the checked checkboxes from data & show them as checked & rest as unchecked

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this hasn't been working (and won't in the already provided answers) is because checkboxes that are not checked won't exist in the $_POST/$_REQUEST arrays.  The other side of that is if they do exist, they must be true.

When you're doing the check to see what the value is, you are causing an error because the key to the array doesn't exist.

Instead, you need to know the available checkboxes and then check if each `isset()` in the array.

Webform:

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $value1; ?>" name="checkbox1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $value2; ?>" name="checkbox2" />
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$checkboxes = array(
    'column1' => 'checkbox1', 
    'column2' => 'checkbox2',
);

foreach ($checkboxes as $column => $checkbox)
{
    $value = (isset($_POST[$checkbox]) ? 1 : 0);
    $sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `$column` = '$value' WHERE `id` = '$member'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When confronted with this, I usually punt and rely on a transaction to update this stuff for me. As you've discovered, unchecked checkboxes won't get submitted with the form, so you'd have to do tedious comparisons to figure out what's changed each time and build up an appropriate update and/or delete query sequence.

Instead, I fire up a transaction, delete all the old checkbox values stored in the DB, and then insert the new ones submitted with this request. Unless you've got the checkboxes acting as foreign keys and/or triggers set on them at the DB level, this is a relatively lightweight option and saves you the trouble of having to compare the old and new lists for changes.